# saving form with associated model

Tags: ember.js, associations, ember-data

It seams simple, but I'm stuck on this one. I have a single controller, and single view dedicated to order model, which has nested client. I create empty records on setupController:

*route:*

```
ShowroomApp.OrdersRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    ShowroomApp.Order.createRecord()
  setupController: (controller,model) ->
    model.set("client", ShowroomApp.Client.createRecord() )
    controller.set("content", model )
```

*controller:*

```
save: ->
  @content.store.commit()
```

On OrdersController i have save action to commit changes made in the form. It results in two separate POST requests each one for each model, but the association doesn't build itself. Orders model saves first, and client_id is obviously null because client doesn't exists yet. Later goes Client post and saves the client, but Order model doesn't know about it and stays without client.

Is there any solution to that?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1):

This is due to an outstanding ember-data issue - [RESTAdapter: Allow new parent, child to be saved at once](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/437)

Check out [Tom Dale's Comment](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/437#issuecomment-9782817) for a possible workaround. It involves manually adding support for saving both records at once.

As an alternative, you might consider adding a `onCreate` callback to the parent record, then creating the child in the callback. If you are ok with having a second commit() this will get the job done.

Comment: Thanks, this issue drove me mad. Finally i've hacked it as you said with didCreate event: @client.one 'didCreate'. I ended up with 3 requests to the server, so it's quite not optimal, but works.

Comment: I've found out that unfortunately adding records manually doesnt work at all. even if i specify the client record as @order.set('client', @client) and reversed @client.get('orders').pushObject @order - update goes to the server with client_id = null

Comment: i ended up serializing records and saving them in controller action using jquery.ajax. it's quite ugly to be honest, so can't wait for proper adapter solution.

Comment: Strange, we are using the onCreate callback in our application. One thing I've noticed is that the parent record's id does not change until after runloop completes. So in the parent's onCreate callback, you need to Ember.run.next